# scripting yum to install a list of packages

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, yum

I am having trouble getting yum to work with a list of packages I want to install. I've tried:
    `yum -y install $(cat /home/pkglist.txt)`
and
    `for i in cat pkglist.txt; do yum -y install $i; done`
and
    `yum -y install $(cat pkglist.txt  | tr '\n' ' ' | tr '\r' ' ')`
but none of them install the packages.
All I get back is:
    
`Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
    Setting up Install Process
     available.perl-CPAN
     available.cpp
     available.fontconfig
     available.gcc
     available.gd
     available.net-snmp-libs
     available.mailcap
     available.perl-libwww-perl
     available.perl-XML-LibXML
     available.perl-DateTime
     available.perl-Time-HiRes
     available.make
     available.net-snmp-perl
     available.perl-Test-Pod
     available.perl-Net-SSLeay
     available.expat-devel
     available.expat
    Error: Nothing to do`

Thanks in advance! -Luke

Comment: Your file has DOS line endings. That's why the output is confused. What output did you get from the attempt that removed them?

Comment: `yum -y install $(cat pkglist.txt  | tr '\n' ' ' | tr '\r' ' ')`  worked like a charm in my test script.  Thanks!

Comment: So you were incorrect when you said it didn't work in your post?

Comment: changed the post - had a different error in the main script causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can this-

```
cat /home/pkglist.txt | xargs yum -y install
```